# загрузочная флешка с windows 10 на linux mint

Tags: linux, windows

Здраствуйте!Можно ли создать загрузочную флешку с Windows10 на Windows 10 и использовать его на компе с Linux Mint для того чтобы вместо  Linux Mint поставить  Windows 10

Comment: Конечно можно...

Comment: спасибо ато никак не могу на linux minte создать флешку  с win10

Comment: @user7860670, я бы ещё добавил "можно, разрешаю."